# EF 4.3 - using TPT still generating Discriminator field on base

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I am having an issue with TPT using EF 4.3 with Code First. I have the following classes:

```
public class Section
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

....

    public int SurveyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
}

public class IntroductionSection : Section
{
    public string ExampleText { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionSection : Section
{
    public int ExampleNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Mapped as follows using Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Section>().Map(m => m.ToTable("Section"));
modelBuilder.Entity<Section>().HasRequired(m => m.Survey).WithMany(s => s.Sections).HasForeignKey(t => t.SurveyId);

modelBuilder.Entity<IntroductionSection>().Map(m => m.ToTable("Introduction"));
modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionSection>().Map(m => m.ToTable("Question"));
```

All seems to be working fine and the three tables are created and populated with the data I expect when seeding - the only issue is that I am still getting a 'Discriminator' field generated in the 'Section' table as I would using TPH. Any ideas why that would be and how I can get rid of it?

I've tried to replicate the issue using simple Animal/Cat/Dog type classes and that (annoyingly) works fine!

Comment: Did you first used TPH and let migrations change it to TPT?

Comment: I have this same issue in Entity Framework 5.0.0. In my case, it's multiple levels of inheritance using TPT. Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have an abstract base class and one of the many derived classes has a discriminator that I'm trying to get rid of with no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem. In my case I had an abstract base class for my models. All models inherited from the base class.

I have used TPT all the way but suddenly there was a discriminator in the database. I've spent some time trying to get rid of the discriminator and finally noticed that I had a view model derived from the model with the discriminator.

I added [NotMapped] attribute to my view model class and the discriminator was no more.